# .NET EF Core context querying Postgresql tries to query unwanted shadow FK column

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

After changing entity, adding or removing properties, a "random" column was added to query and it's causing problems.

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column u.UserOldId does not exist
```

I am querying this entity

```
[Table("user_visuals", Schema = "present")]
    public class UserVisual
    {
        #region Columns
        [Key]
        [Column("user_visual_id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Column("user_id")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        [Column("visual_id")]
        public long VisualId { get; set; }
        [Column("render_position")]
        public int RenderPosition { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Relations
        public Visual Visual { get; set; } = default!;
        //public UserOld User { get; set; } = default!;
        #endregion
    }
```

After some investigation I've found out that context somehow contains shadow FK and tries to query it though it doesn't exist
[image: DB example]

Seems like context has this kind of information about it

```
EntityType: UserVisual
  Properties: 
    Id (long) Required PK AfterSave:Throw ValueGenerated.OnAdd
      Annotations: 
        Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy: IdentityByDefaultColumn
        Relational:ColumnName: user_visual_id
    RenderPosition (int) Required
      Annotations: 
        Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy: None
        Relational:ColumnName: render_position
    UserId (long) Required FK Index
      Annotations: 
        Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy: None
        Relational:ColumnName: user_id
    UserOldId (no field, long?) Shadow FK Index
      Annotations: 
        Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy: None
    VisualId (long) Required FK Index
      Annotations: 
        Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy: None
        Relational:ColumnName: visual_id
  Navigations: 
    Visual (Visual) ToPrincipal Visual Inverse: UserVisuals
  Keys: 
    Id PK
  Foreign keys: 
    UserVisual {'UserId'} -> User {'Id'} ToDependent: Visuals Cascade
    UserVisual {'UserOldId'} -> UserOld {'Id'} ToDependent: Visuals ClientSetNull
    UserVisual {'VisualId'} -> Visual {'Id'} ToDependent: UserVisuals ToPrincipal: Visual Cascade
  Indexes: 
    UserId 
    UserOldId 
    VisualId 
  Annotations: 
    DiscriminatorProperty: 
    Relational:FunctionName: 
    Relational:Schema: present
    Relational:SqlQuery: 
    Relational:TableName: user_visuals
    Relational:ViewName: 
    Relational:ViewSchema:
```

Context configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserIdentity>()
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<long>>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.RoleId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserVisual>().HasOne<Visual>(x => x.Visual).WithMany(x => x.UserVisuals).HasForeignKey(x => x.VisualId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserDevice>().HasOne<Device>(x => x.Device).WithMany(x => x.UserDevices).HasForeignKey(x => x.DeviceId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Device>().HasOne<DeviceType>(x => x.DeviceType).WithMany(x => x.Devices).HasForeignKey(x => x.TypeId);
        }
```

Out of ideas, what should I do?

Comment: Most likely `UserOld` is still [included in the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model). And if it has collection navigation property to `UserVisual` (`ICollection<UserVisual>` or similar), it is enough to define a relationship by default, thus shadow FK at the dependent side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phantom shadow FKs usually indicate some relationship misconfiguration via fluent API, or like in this case, relationship created by EF Core default conventions.

Note that [Single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property) in one of the entities is enough to imply relationship in the model. So even if you removed the reference navigation property from the dependent entity (`UserOld User` in `UserVisual`), if the principal type (`UserOld` in this case) is still [included in the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model), and has collection navigation property referring to the dependent entity type (`ICollection<UserVisual` or similar), EF Core still considers a relationship with conventional shadow FK.

So, always check the usage (find all references) of a entity class inside other entities navigation properties, and remove the ones which are not intended to create relationship. Also (even though it's not the case here) the correct pairing of `Has` / With` calls to not leave existing navigation property out of the fluent configuration, thus creating additional conventional relationship.